# PHP composer require exclusive dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php

I m wondering how to tell composer that I need either `ext-imagick` or `ext-gmagick`. But not both !

As suggested i added some virtual package:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "virtual/imagine-gd",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "require": {
                "ext-gd": "*"
            },
            "provide": {
                "virtual/imagine-impl": "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "virtual/imagine-gmagick",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "require": {
                "ext-gmagick": "*"
            },
            "provide": {
                "virtual/imagine-impl": "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "virtual/imagine-imagick",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "require": {
                "ext-imagick": "*"
            },
            "provide": {
                "virtual/imagine-impl": "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

and added the require:

```
"virtual/imagine-impl": "^1.0"
```

but go the error:

```
The requested package virtual/imagine-impl could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

Answer (score 2):

hope i can help you by this by taking your variably in dependent logic and isolating into a small package that allows and requires a virtual package.

```
`{
  "name": "my/gd-impl",
  "require": {
    "ext-gd": "*"
  },
  "provide": {
    "my/image-processor": "1.0.0"
  }
}


{
  "name": "my/imagick-impl",
  "require": {
    "ext-imagick": "*"
  },
  "provide": {
    "my/image-processor": "1.0.0"
  }
}


{
  "name": "my/gmagick-impl",
  "require": {
    "ext-gmagick": "*"
  },
  "provide": {
    "my/image-processor": "1.0.0"
  }
}


{
  "name": "my/awesome-project",
  "require": {
    "my/image-processor": "^1.0.0"
  }
}`
```

Comment: whoo ! cooool !! So i could use a `repositories` entry with many `type = package` ?